# Bibtex : Alpha-style citation without year

Tags: bibtex

I use bibtex with `\bibliographystyle{alpha}`.
How can I cite only the first letter of each author, and remove the year?

Examples : (a) instead of [CHN13] , display [CHN] ;
   (b) instead of [Sil08] , display [S]

Does anyone know a simple way to hack a `.bst` file to achieve that?

This could sound akward. But my goal is to minimize the place taken by citations, while keeping the references identifiable. Hence, I intend to change by hand the bibitems in the .bbl file, in the cases where multiple labels occur.

I have seen two similar questions, any answer for them would be equally interesting :
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186681/llncs-alpha-numeric-reference-style?rq=1
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180187/alpha-style-citation-callout-without-year

I have also looked into the manual "makebst" but I am unfamiliar with the language so couldn't understand where this issue is dealt.

I am constrained to use Bibtex, because I also submit to journals which accept only `.bst` files, or ordinary `.bbl` files.

(Reagarding my goal, it would be interesting to have a `.bst` file that resolves conflicts of multiple bibitems, adding a numerical counter when this happens. Though this looks hard to implement)

Comment: My take is that the alpha bibliography style is a compromise between the numeric style -- very space-efficient callouts, but no hint as to what the callouts are about -- and the authoryear style -- the citation callouts are quite informative as to who the authors are, but each callout takes up a lot of space. What you're proposing risks losing the modest benefits of the `alpha` style (i.e., the citation callout being at least somewhat informative) without obtaining a significant benefit in terms of saving space. If you need the document to be shorter, lose a few paragraphs here or there...

Comment: (First, thank you very much mico for having taken time on my question. I also wish I had enough reputation to upvote your other very usefull contributions).

Comment: Then, regarding my question, actually, just removing the year would be also fine. Indeed, more than a gain of space, my intention is also semantic. In fact, reading and writing maths articles, I found that, when citing sources with the year (like alpha), attention is driven to the most recent references. But actually, old books or papers have the same value as long as the results remains true and their formulation up to date. This is why I was aiming at an author-number system.